# Scrollable Modal with Max Height that will only be as tall as its contents

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, scrollbar

I'm trying to get a modal window that will size with its content up to 80% of the height of the window, and then scroll. I also need the close button (represented by the "X" in the top-right) to stay fixed. This is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div class="dialog-overlay"></div>
  <div class="dialog" style="left:75%;">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <div class="dialog-wrap">
      <div class="dialog-content">
        <!-- Long amounts of content here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dialog-overlay {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 88;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.dialog {
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  width: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 89;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 80px #000;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dialog .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 20px;
}

.dialog-wrap {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.dialog-content {
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

With this code, I got as far as the codepen below, but I'm stuck. The one on the right works as desired, but then the one on the left, where the content is small, is too big with unnecessary empty space. If I comment out the "height: 80%" from .dialog, the one on the left is fixed, but then the scrolling one on the right ceases to work correctly. I don't want to have to set the height, but it seems to be required for the inner content to scroll for some reason, even though I thought max-height should do it as well.

http://codepen.io/evshell18/pen/QNPyGr

Comment: Looks like you may just be missing an `overflow-y:auto;` for your `.dialog` class. I removed the `height` and added `overflow-y` and it seems to work as you described. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwWrWL

Comment: Second that, your X will need to be moved outside of that scrollable area. :)

Comment: @Markus You highlighted exactly why I couldn't do that. I had something similar to that at first, but the X scrolled along with the contents. I had the parent .dialog with 2 children: .close and .dialog-content and the X was scrolling with the contents, so I added .dialog-wrap to try to separate out and fix the X.